# Запятая перед «значит», НО не после

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Мне интересно, как это работает. Вот «Грамота» в своих ответах очень часто выделяет *значит* запятой только с одной стороны (когда это слово стоит между частями сложного предложения или однородными членами). Насколько я понял, *значит* выделяется **с двух сторон**, если является частью союза ЕСЛИ..., ЗНАЧИТ; РАЗ..., ЗНАЧИТ. А если при этом слове нет слова *раз* или *если*, то без запятой после. Хотя другие источники указывают на то, что это слово выделяется с двух сторон **всегда**. Ну не знаю, лично мне кажется, лучше доверять «Грамоте», чем тем источникам. Можете в поисковике этого портала ввести «, значит» и «, значит,», по этому можно сделать такой вывод. Только смотрите именно ответы, и ответы те, где *значит* соединяет части СП или однор. члены.

А вы как считаете по поводу обособления? Знаете, как правильно?

Comment: Йоу, почему так много минусов на моëм вопросе?

Comment: Ладно, ответ я получил, думаю, что вопрос лучше удалить, а то, не дай бог, еще минусы прилетят.

Comment: Мне кажется, что Ajgy плюсует и минусует с других аккаунтов. За ответы без доказательств здесь не голосуют. Их даже удаляют. Его ответ по правилам вообще надо удалить.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А если удалить, репутация не упадет? Если да, насколько?

Comment: Если удалить, баллы не вернутся. За каждый минус всего лишь -2. Это мелочь. Не надо удалять.

Comment: Хорошо, прислушаюсь к Вашему мнению.

Comment: Максим, удалять ни в коем случае нельзя, они только этого и ждут. Ваша репутация упадет ненамного, а уважения вам от нас только прибавится. Это принципиально важный вопрос. Меня минусуют те же люди,  даже тему пытаются закрыть.  Поэтому надо противостоять им. Я дала на ваш вопрос ссылку, да и комментарии из чата пропадут.  Я однажды пробовала удалять вопросы с ответами, и система прислала мне предупреждение. Часто нельзя так делать, а то не разрешат спрашивать. Я сразу раздумала.

Comment: Сейчас -2, а было +1. Вот и считайте 10 - 6 = 4.  Вы еще в плюсе))

Comment: @Sharon  Сейчас -2 (четыре минуса, два плюса), получается 20 - 8 = 12. Эт я так, для точности :))

Comment: Десант, наверное, а я не герой... Надо подумать) Лучше уж под стол ( как в песне про Петруху).

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо за ответ и объяснение. Я считаю, что Вы правы, и соглашусь с Вами

Comment: @Максим *Я считаю, что Вы правы, и соглашусь с Вами* — интересный стилистический момент: из-за того, что "считаю" — настоящее, "соглашусь" звучит так, будто согласитесь в будущем. То есть не надо объединять будущее в значении настоящего с реальным настоящим.

Comment: @oleedd, а это тоже есть в правилах русского языка? Это считается грамматической ошибкой?

Comment: @Максим Это стилистика, не грамматика. Они даже правила пунктуации и орфографии доделать не могут. По стилистике вряд ли возможно сделать. Потому что это нельзя систематизировать. Если другие тоже так воспринимают, то точно ошибка (неуместное употребление слова).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как это работает?** Да, понимать это важно, а иначе придется **слушать и слушаться.** Или сравнивать источники: кто правее? Куда как лучше решать задачи по смыслу и своему понимаю этого смысла, когда **приходится выбирать** вариант при неоднозначности мнений.

1. **О разных решениях задачи.**

В основе разных мнений лежит тема (1) **условно-следственных** и (2) **следственных отношений** в СПП и БСП.  В СПП такие отношения выражают союзы:   (1) ***ЕСЛИ…ТО*** и ***ТАК ЧТО.***  Разница большая.

(1) **Условно следственные отношения** (если… то) связаны с противопоставлением (если так, то вот так), это разделительная интонация (повышение тона перед паузой).

(2) При **чисто следственных** отношениях (факт/событие – следствие) предлагается **вывод** в качестве дополнительной информации, поэтому интонация присоединительная (понижение тона перед паузой).

2. Кроме основного союза ***ЕСЛИ...ТО*** в СПП используются и другие варианты, в том числе двойной союз ***ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ***.  Вводное слово здесь на правах второй части союза, при этом оно остается **вводным словом** и обособляется (две запятые).
3. **[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220)**

**Союз.** Соединяет предложения или части сложного предложения  (в том числе в составе двойного союза «если... значит» или «раз... значит»). Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», **СОЮЗ «ЗНАЧИТ» ОТДЕЛЯЕТСЯ ЗАПЯТОЙ** (реже тире) от последующей части предложения.

Итак, обособление этого «союза» указано, но грамматика не такая точная: здесь вводное слово названо союзом, а в грамматике это структурный элемент **во второй части двойного союза.** Но из-за грамматической неточности следуют все проблемы: появляется желание не обособлять этот «союз».

**4.  Бессоюзное предложение**

Теперь союза  «если» нет, а «значит» присутствует: *Послал он мне крест – **значит, меня он любит.***

Предложение из Справочника, а какое это предложение?  В грамматике это БСП, вводное слово «значит» на правах структурного элемента, но союзом не является. (Снова возможность для разного понимания темы.)  Отношение в этом предложении **условно-следственные.**

А как выразить **чисто следственные отношения** в БСП, ведь союзов там нет? Можно использовать  наречия «поэтому, следовательно».

**Примечание**. «Следовательно»  здесь **не вводное слово**. **[Вводное слово](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_675)** Указывает на связь мыслей, последовательность их изложения; то же, что «стало быть», «таким образом». Тоже дискуссионный вопрос, который решается неоднозначно (обратим внимание).

**Получаем:** *Сегодня дождь, **поэтому** на  дачу не поедем. Сегодня дождь, **следовательно** на  дачу не поедем. Сегодня дождь – **значит**, на  дачу не поедем.* Сегодня дождь, **а значит**, на дачу не поедем.

**5. Однородные члены**

*Мироздание оживет, все в мире станет живым, **а значит**, свободным. В эти месяцы Василиса вынужденно осталась единственной собеседницей, **а вернее,** слушательницей Павла Алексеевича.*

**[В грамматике (стр. 108)](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)** сказано:

Дифференцировать соединительные, противительные, разделительные отношения между членами ряда могут также **частицы, наречия и наречные обороты, модальные слова:** *тем не менее, вместе с тем, одновременно, все-таки, все же, хотя бы, особенно,  в особенности, тем более, **может быть**, главное, даже, иногда, временами, по возможности* и т.п.

Итак, **вводное слово** «может быть»  здесь названо, и его роль в предложениях с однородными членами понятна.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148623/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

Уже сто раз об этом говорилось. "Если...значит/раз...значит" - это те союзы, в которых запятая ставится только перед второй частью двойного союза.