# Обособление слова «значит» в значении союза: каким справочником нужно пользоваться?

Tags: вводные-слова, невыделение-вводных

1. Вопрос был задан на основании **мнения автора** о выборе решения и справочника в следующей теме:
   [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475134/Союз-на-границе-частей-СП](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475134/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A1%D0%9F)

**Из комментариев**: — Я сайтам как-то не доверяю... (Это про Грамоту.ру или про Справочник по пунктуации.)  — Я больше склоняюсь все же к тому варианту. — А вы уверены в правильности выбора?  (Это про Справочник Остроумовой, Фрамполь). Возможно, автор до конца не уверен в решении, но принимает однозначный ответ.

2. Решение этой задачи в **[Справочнике по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_220)**
   **(Москва, 2012)** не соответствует решению в  книге: **Словарь вводных слов**, **сочетаний и предложений.** Опыт словаря-справочника. **Изд-во СГУ, 2009.** О.А. Остроумова О.Д. Фрамполь  «Трудности русской пунктуации».

**В качестве справки**

В первом источнике вводное слово «значит» **в значении союза** обособляется, а во втором — нет. Конечно, к первому доверия больше: книга одобрена академическими кругами, в том числе **Лопатиным В.В**., и это наиболее **позднее** издание. Оно ближе к современной точке зрения, чем справочник, изданный Саратовским университетом в 2009 году.

3. Меня интересует, как воспринимается отсутствие обособления **обычными пользователями** (как они делают выбор и почему).  Ведь это может показаться странным — видеть известное вводное слово  без обособления, в том числе в функции союза.

Я тоже отвечу на этот вопрос.

Спасибо.

**Обсуждение похожей темы**

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475130/Запятая-перед-значит-НО-не-после](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475130/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%9D%D0%9E-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5)

Многие участники форума (в этом вопросе) открыто заявили о своем несогласии с тем, что **игнорируется** решение Справочника по пунктуации.

Comment: «_Оно ближе к современной точке зрения, чем справочник **Фрамполя**…_» === Фрамполь Ольга Дмитриевна — **женщина**.

Comment: Издание — это же версия того же. Надо поправить. Подумал, что вы о разных изданиях Грамоты. У них раньше было с одной запятой. Интернет это сохранил: https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/253/значит

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрела книгу.  Нет, все как было.  А вот по вашей ссылке какой-то другой материал.

Comment: Что у вас за книга? Ниже написано: *Словарь-справочник по пунктуации. — М.: Справочно-информационный интернет-портал ГРАМОТА.РУ. В. В. Свинцов, В. М. Пахомов, И. В. Филатова. 2010.*

Comment: Но уже там есть примечание об этом. Практика письма важнее, чем правила. И решение Грамоты это демонстрирует.

Comment: А вот откуда Лопатин взял, что так надо писать? Ни одного примера из литературы нет. Только один пример, который везде тиражируется: *На небе собираются тучи, значит будет дождь.* Во времена Розенталя явно такого не было. Чем не реформа?

Comment: Авторы те же, текст статьи тот же, а год 2012-й.  И еще: Впервые в алфавитном порядке, Лопатин и Морковкин внесли много ценных замечаний, за что им благодарность.  Может, раньше был не алфавитный порядок.

Comment: Значит, в 2012 уже изменили.

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что в справочнике Лопатина тоже с одной? https://orfogrammka.ru/правила_русской_орфографии_и_пунктуации_лопатин/знаки_препинания_при_вводных_и_вставных_конструкциях/ (§96)

Comment: Для меня Розенталь авторитетнее, чем Лопатин. Он явно умнее. Гораздо больше написал (больше, чем коллектив РАН). Создал стилистику. Считается легендарным лингвистом. Не слышал, чтобы кого-то ещё считали. В Интернете пишут, что Розенталь славится логическими обоснованиями, чего нет у Лопатина. Но они друг друга дополняют во многом.

Comment: Я в курсе, конечно, и работаю вэтой теме только по Розенталю.  Мне кажется странным видеть слово необособленным и при этом НАЗЫВАТЬ его вводным словом.  Тогда это уже не вводное слово, а нечто другое (функция изменилась). Что там редактировал Лопатин, я не знаю, но в 2012 году Справочник опубликовали именно в таком виде.

Comment: Для меня тоже странно. Это явное упрощение.

Answer (score 1):

Мне ближе решение в **Справочнике по пунктуации** 2012 года.

Рассмотрим предложение из **[недавнего вопроса на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/475134/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A1%D0%9F)**

*Придет из-за нашего шума повариха — **значит(,)** мы получим нагоняй!*

Сравним **два варианта**:

(1)  *Придет из-за нашего шума повариха — **значит,** мы получим нагоняй!*

(2) *Придет из-за нашего шума повариха — **значит** мы получим нагоняй!*

Орфографический  редактор **подчеркнул**  необособленное слово «значит», и у меня тоже есть желание его обособить.

**Почему?** Эта фраза должна обозначать **условно-следственные** отношения: *если придет — то получим.*  А она обозначает  **последовательность событий** в будущем времени: *придет — и получим.* Ведь форма "придет" должна бы обозначать условие, а здесь получается обычная последовательность.

Comment: *Эта фраза должна обозначать условно-следственные отношения: если придет — то получим. А она обозначает следствие: вот придет — тогда получим (а пока подождем).* — про два варианта интересно, но причины не видно, со "значит" второй не получается.

Comment: Всё равно ничего не понятно.

Comment: Мне думается, что форма "придет" может иметь условное значение (тема  сослагательного значения в изъявительном наклонении).  Я это уточню позже, сейчас нет времени.

Comment: Ну так оно условное. А временное (*когда придет, тогда получим*) со "значит" не получается.

Comment: Если переставить первое слово, то ещё один смысл: *Из-за нашего шума придёт повариха — значит, мы получим нагоняй!*

Comment: Это уже следствие (без условия) Еще можно так прочитать: Из-за нашего шума придёт повариха — означает мы получим нагоняй!  Это если не обособлять вводное слово, значение глагола.

Comment: Это неверно. Надо "означает, что" (две основы, СПП). Если без "что", то с запятой, как со "значит", но это звучит ужасно (стилистика).

Comment: Я о чем и говорю, что понять можно, а звучит ужасно.  Вот я вижу это глагольное значение, и оно меня раздражает. Поэтому надо обособлять "значит".

Comment: Да, глагольное значение. Часть речи-то глагол. Вводное слово представляет собой какую-то часть речи.